# Importing data from excel into matlab with both numbers and characters in the same cells

Tags: excel, matlab

The data exists of Bank statements including descriptions. I've imported these bank statements from a .swi file into an excel file, which worked fine.
When imported to matlab with the:

```
[NUM, TXT, RAW] = xlsread(filename)
```

function, it worked but it did give the following warning:

> Warning: Could not start Excel server for import, 'basic' mode will be used. 
>   Refer to
>   HELP XLSREAD for more information. 
>   In xlsread at 186

Which is strange because the university computer i'm using has excel. After importing, the data does show itself correctly in the RAW-matrix only it has high comma's in each cell, for example:

> 'C150331EUR000000001352,14'

When trying to make a function work with the data it does not function properly with a range of different errors, while the functions i'm using do work on random teststrings.

Anyone any idea how to make this data work?

Comment: Please provide an example input string (or better yet a small version of the `.xls` file) and the desired output (be it a collection of vectors, a cell array, structures or anything else). Please be as specific as you can.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/19264-problems-starting-excel-server  may be because of the office installation

Comment: The office installation could indeed be the problem. I installed matlab on my own laptop and it did not give the same problems as it did on the university computers. Thanks for the help anyway!